# How to cut texture into two equal pieces in wp7 xna?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Hello everyone,
           I am trying to make an application similar to fruit ninja where i need to cut the object into two pieces.So i wanted to know whether any fundamental API's exist to do the same.